# Installing module in the same file that module is used

Tags: python, keyboard

I have put this in the top of my code:

`os.system("pip install keyboard")`

to install the keyboard module, however my code wont run because in that same code i am importing keyboard. i am wondering if i will have to do them separately or if i can import and use the module in the same code without problems.

i have tried importing the module after pip installing it but where the import doesn't matter so it still wont run without Keyboard being installed.

Comment: Why are you installing a module from your script (which will happen *every* time you run the script) instead of installing it *once* before you run the script?

Comment: basically i am making a code for fun where i put it on my friends mac and run it so i need it to install the module in the code so i can just run the code and let it go so its faster. yes this sounds like malware because it is but not used badly, im just havin fun with it with me friends.

Comment: i have never seen this before...  `pip install module` in the environment and then do `import module` in the code.

Comment: at the moment i am getting this in terminal as a responce     'import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard' '      so the coed wont run because keyboard is missing which might just mean that i cant and i have to install keyboard manually but theat kind of makes it useless.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't get all of this self-contained in one python file, but this could be a useful alternative.

You could consider writing two files.  One is the python file which imports and uses keyboard -- call this `keyboard_script.py`.  The second could be a bash script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

pip install keyboard
python keyboard_script.py
```

This bash script first installs keyboard then runs your python script which uses keyboard.  Then you have to share both the bash script and the python file, but only the bash script needs to be run since it automatically calls the python file.

Comment: this could work, but to save me from having to get 2 files on their computer is there a way i can pull the python file from online from like github or something and still run it from that first file?